# Power Bi SQL - Semantic Query not supported

Tags: sql, r, powerbi, plotly, powerquery

I've tried building my own visual in R and got to the point where I can import it and use it normally.
However, the data displayed is hardcoded, so I wanted to add the option to display Data from Fields.

The query I'm using looks like this:

```
SELECT [Cost_Center], 
       [Machine], 
       [DownTime_Group], 
       [DownTime_Desc], 
       [Cost_Center_Level4], 
       [Production_Plan_Start_DATETIME] as SDT,
       [Production_Plan_End_DATETIME] as EDT
FROM [DWH_IT].[Downtime_PBI] (20210801, 20210803)
WHERE Downtime_Reason_Code <> '13'                    /* 13 = Turned off */
```

When I tried it using the same data I'd normally get in the query I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DVmO.png) error (header is in german, sbt)...
I couldn't find any information about this specific Exception, can somebody explain it to me?

This is my R-code:

```
source('r_files/flatten_HTML.r')

############### Library Declarations ###############
require(vistime)
require(plotly)
require(DBI)
require(odbc)
require(htmlwidgets)
require(ggplot2)

name <- dataset$Name
start <- dataset$SDT
end <- dataset$EDT
group <- dataset$Group
col <- c()
len <- length(dataset$DownTime_Group);

for (i in 1: len) {
  dtg <- dataset$DownTime_Group[i]
  if (dtg == "Setup") {
    col[i] <- "green"
  } else if (dtg == "Repair") {
    col[i] <- "red"
  } else if (dtg == "Other") {
    col[i] <- "blue"
  } else {
    col[i] <- "yellow"
  }
}

timeline_data <- base::data.frame(event = name,
start = start,
end   = end,
group = group,
color = col)
g <- vistime::vistime(timeline_data, optimize_y = TRUE, show_labels = FALSE)

############# Create and save widget ###############
p <- ggplotly(g)
internalSaveWidget(g, 'out.html')
```

Here is an [in depth error log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PPaH4s5pOtCw-RVfSv96It60t_hi39Bi/view)

Best regards

Comment: Is this really related to the SQL _language_? If so, show us the problem SQL. [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh I added the SQL-Code I'm using to fetch the data for my visual. Best regards

Comment: Also show us the error message.

Comment: Is the link broken? You should see it just under the code example.... [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DVmO.png) should work as well

Comment: A question here should be self-contained. SO is a great Q&A archive, but questions (and answers) with links will lose information as soon as the link is out-of-date. I.e. don't use external hosts to provide information.

Comment: Ok, now the question is self contained. Do you have any expertise in SQL/PowerBi custom visuals and know what this Exception means?

Comment: If possible, please include the *text* of the error itself, not an image of it: images break screen-readers and cannot be copied/searched (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). (I'm not a BI expert, btw, still looking though.)